# MySQL performance: is String prefix + Number as ID OK?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a snowflake ID (such as 49839556967183364) as primary key, now I want to prefix it with some String like "QR49839556967183364".

Does this String prefix lower down MySQL performance regarding to indexing and ordering?

Comment: Wait...if you already have a unique PK column, then what is the point of prefixing it?

Comment: *I have a snowflake ID (such as 49839556967183364) as primary key* Its datatype is BIGINT? *Does this String prefix lower down MySQL performance regarding to indexing and ordering?* If this cause PK datatype change from BIGINT to VARCHAR then it is very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The performance difference between a `BIGINT` and a `VARCHAR(22)` is not significant.  Focus optimizations at a higher level.

Be aware that you cannot do `AUTO_INCREMENT` on part of a column.

(Caveat:  If you plan on having a billion rows in that table, I will change my tune.)